# How to add files from a specific directory in git? and then commit it

Tags: git, github, addition, commit

I have many files in vs code that they are not committed yet I want to add one folder with all files in it is there any way to do it

the is a command `git add --all` but it adds also all files that I don't want to add just files in the folder that I am in it I want to add and commit.

Comment: Try `git add folder_name`

Comment: actually I have many files that I don't want to commit them they are from another project I want to add all files from a folder NOT other files from another folder that are not committed yet.

Comment: How many projects you have in one repository? If you want to add just one folder to the staging area, you can use `git add folder`. It will add just that folder and all of its files into the staging area. Then you can commit.

Comment: Now it is solved the problem was that I was not in parent folder. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do `git add <folder name>` and then any changed files in that folder will be added to git when committed.